# Grub rescue mode, bios in order, won't boot from window 7 recovery CD nor Ubuntu 14.04 live cd, nor usb key

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader, live-cd, grubrescue

Alright.

I have (had) an Acer Aspire 4739z. Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

I have a grub rescue mode problem since booting in Rescue Mode (by mistake of course). 
And now the fun starts.

My ls command tells me

> (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0, msdos1)

But every command,

> ls (hd0),
>   ls (hd0,msdos0 to 7)
>   or,
>   ls (hd0,0 to 7)
>   , gives the ''unknowed filesystem'' answer.

Then, knowing that, I tried the hard way, booting from a CD or USB key. And that didn't work neither. 
My boot order in my Bios is

> 1. ATAPI CDROM : HL-DT-STDVDRAM GT32N,
> 2. USB CDROM,
> 3. USB FDD,
> 4. USB HDD,
> 5. NETWORK BOOT,
> 6. HDD : WDC WD500...

It then just tries loading for a while and then return to... the grub rescue mode.

I can wipe everything since I had no unsaved data on the computer and I would prefer an option that allows me to use Windows 7 first (since my Ubuntu DVD and USB key are in another town)

Comment: I just found the Acer eRecovey Management who allows me to restore Windows (by pressing alt + F10. But it still can't boot afterward, but it is the more hope I had in a week; I wasn't in grub rescue mode...